# Trying to install R on my Mac and i am getting the following error

Tags: r

> uring startup - Warning messages:
> 1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
> 2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
> 3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
> 4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
> 5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
> [R.app GUI 1.76 (7976) x86_64-apple-darwin17.0]
>
> WARNING: You're using a non-UTF8 locale, therefore only ASCII characters will work.
> Please read R for Mac OS X FAQ (see Help) section 9 and adjust your system preferences accordingly.

Comment: I understand that there was a solution that was published however the same is not working for me

Comment: Hi! If you provide more information on how you are trying to install R, I believe you will get better answers more quickly.